# React Native PjSip returns account active false and unable to make call

Tags: pjsip, pjsua2

Can anyone please guide me about the pjsip as I have to implement SIP call in my app. Whenever I try to register an account it gives me account active false. I have added the snap:[image]

Comment: Did you get this resolved? I'm having the same issue with iOS; however it does work on Android.

Comment: yes check this out [link](https://github.com/datso/react-native-pjsip/issues/231)